# How to only display full rows in react-native ListView?

Tags: listview, react-native

I'm rendering a ListView component and want to avoid rendering partial rows.

[image]

below is my code which highlights the first index within the `visible` prop

#### within `render()` method

```
  return (
    <ListView
      onChangeVisibleRows={this.handleChangeVisibleRows}
      style={styles.containerStyle}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderRow}
    />
   )
  }
```

#### within `ListView` Container

```
  renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow){
    return (
      <MyRow
        {...rowData}
        key={rowData['obj.id']}
        highlighted={this.state.highlighted === rowID}
      />
    );
  }

  handleChangeVisibleRows(visible, changed) {
    var sectionIDs = Object.keys(visible); 
    var itemIDs = Object.keys(visible[sectionIDs[0]]);
    var first = itemIDs[0];
    this.setState({
      highlighted: first
    })
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, don't have time for a full answer:
1. create a function that calculates the height of each row a factor of the height of the screen
2. ListView allows you to use the props for ScrollView.  Use the ScrollView props, snapToInterval and snapToAlignment, to make sure the list scrolls in whole values